# How to properly connect and configure PC to TV

Tags: video, hdmi, tv, htpc

When I connect my PC (Windows 7) or Mac (Yosemite) to my FullHD Plasma TV, it is properly recognized. However the whole experience is not as good as with a 'native' media player device.

The following points bug me:

- Stutter: When playing media files that have a different frame rate than the refresh rate of the TV, there is a visible stuttering in the video. I could manually open the video files, check the frame rate, adjust the refresh rate and go, but this process is cumbersome.
- Colors: The colors seem somehow 'off', lacking contrast in general and detail in dark scenes.

Note: These effects do not appear when using my PS3 with the same media (e. g. a DVD) on the same HDMI port of my TV with the same settings on my TV. I also tried specialized software like Kodi, which offers automatic refresh rate to frame rate sync (according to the settings menu), but that does not work for me (the stuttering remains).

What are the necessary steps 'properly' set up the PC as a media center?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what parameters the TV needs to have to do this (I only have one to try with), but you might be able to improve the detail in dark areas and contrast.

Specifically for an Asus GTX 660 Ti and Sony Bravia KDL-32W5500, there is a setting in the NVIDIA control panel under "Display"->"Adjust desktop colour settings": "Dynamic range". Set it to 0-255 instead of 16-235.

It works for both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1, but that option is not available on my other display, which is an old low-cost 1080p Asus monitor. The same option *may* be available in Intel or AMD GPU drivers, and will certainly be available with some other TVs and Nvidia-powered display cards.

I was surprised by how much better my NASA desktop background images now look, even though it's only an LCD panel rather than plasma.